# Best way to shorten arguments passed to a method

Tags: ruby

What's the best way to pass long length of variables, as arguments, to a method?

```
def foo(a,b,c,d,e,f) # Could this be shorter? No?
  puts f + " loves " + e
  # dad loves you
end

egg = "Chicken"
girl = "Money"
car = "luxury"
rich = "poor"
me = "you"
mom = "dad"

foo(egg, girl, car, rich, me, mom)
```

Is there something down the lines of `foo(a..f)`? Yes, that wont work but was looking for something short and neat, if possible.

Comment: Try to rewrite your functions so they just take less arguments. A function with an arity of 6 is getting a little high.

Comment: you can always pass a hash (opts), `def foo(opts); end` like: `foo(me: :you, mom: :dad)`, and then access it in method as `opts[:me]`. I don't know about shorter, but easier, because you don't have to be precise about arguments' order - it's only one argument

Comment: I would argue that you should re-think your design. When a method takes six arguments (and it needs all of them), then it probably does too many things. Most of the time three arguments should be possible - imaging this signature: `who.does_someting(:to_who, :with_this_tool, :how_to_do)`. You example is a bit problematic, because you asks how to avoid so many args, when you use only two. The solution is obvious: just remove the unused args.

Comment: Thanks. Both comments and answer worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the possible ways to call methods are described in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html):

```
egg = "Chicken"
girl = "Money"
car = "luxury"
rich = "poor"
me = "you"
mom = "dad"
```

#### Option 1. Use splat

```
def foo(*args)
  puts "#{args[-1]} loves #{args[-2]}"
end
foo(*[egg, girl, car, rich, me, mom])  # dad loves you
```

#### Option 2. Use double splat

```
def foo(**params)
  puts "#{params[:mom]} loves #{params[:me]}"
end
foo(me: me, mom: mom)  # dad loves you
```

double splat with defaults:

```
def foo(me: 'you', mom:,  **params)
  puts "#{mom} loves #{me}"
end
foo(mom: mom)  # dad loves you
```

Answer (score 0):

### Splat (*) operator

Methods can take any number of arguments by prefixing a parameter with a * (splat) or a ** (double splat) operator. This is useful when the exact number of arguments is unknown at method definition.

First let's look at the * (splat) operator. All arguments passed through the parameter prefixed with * are automatically stored in an array.

```
def list_masters *names
    print names
end

# Call the method and pass it three arguments
list_masters "Shunryu Suzuki", "Thich Nhat Hanh", "Kodo Sawaki"
Output:
["Shunryu Suzuki", "Thich Nhat Hanh", "Kodo Sawaki"]
```

Notice the output is an array.

There are other uses for the splat operator in Ruby, such as unwraping an array when passing it to a method, coercing values into arrays and deconstructing arrays, but these are outside the scope of this post.

### Double splat (**) operator

Now let's look at the ** (double splat) operator. It was was introduced in Ruby 2.0 and works in a similar way to the single splat operator, except it stores the arguments in a hash instead of an array. Let's try it:

```
def meditate **details
    print details
end

# Call the method and pass it three arguments
meditate mat: "zabuton", cushion: "zafu", practice: "shikantaza", time: 40
Output:
{:mat=>"zabuton", :cushion=>"zafu", :practice=>"shikantaza", :time=>40}
```

Notice that the output is a hash.

Parameters prefixed with double splat only accept keyword arguments, such as minutes: 40 or meditation: "zazen".

### Mixing * and ** operators

If a method includes both single splat and double splat parameters, non-keyword arguments will be taken by the parameter prefixed with * and hash arguments will be taken by the parameter prefixed with **. Example:

```
def meditate *practices, **details
    puts "Practices: #{practices}"
    puts "Details: #{details}"
end

meditate"zazen", "kinhin", duration: 40, time: "morning"
Output:
Practices: ["zazen", "kinhin"]
Details: {:duration=>40, :time=>"morning"}
```

Notice that the arguments passed through the *practices parameter were inserted into an array and arguments passed through the **details parameter were stored into a hash.

When a method includes both * and ** parameters, all of the positional arguments should be provided first, then the keyword arguments. If we try to call the above method and provide the keyword arguments first, a syntax error is thrown:

```
meditate time: "morning", duration: 40, "zazen", "kinhin"
Output:
SyntaxError: (irb):59: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
meditate time: "morning", duration: 40, "zazen", "kinhin"
                                            ^
```